# Anchor tag mailto issue in pdf

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf

Im using laravel PDF to convert HTML contents to pdf, but in pdf file anchor tag is not clickable. Seems issue is with acute accent, but im confused how to fix this issue. Below is the HTML code:

`<a href="mailto:atenciónalcliente@abc.com" target="_blank">atenciónalcliente@abc.com</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the acute accent then a "hackish" solution is to convert the String to ASCII using iconv, for example:

```php
$email = 'atenciónalcliente@abc.com';
$asciiEmail = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $email);
```

Fiddle: https://onlinephp.io/c/2ae17

Comment: But that will be two separate mail id's right?

Comment: @aaabell - yes that is correct however looking into this a bit more you should be encoding unicode email addresses. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_email